# Are all solutions of $ f_n (x)^{2n} + f_n ' (x)^{2n} = 1$ periodic?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation, periodic-functions, square-numbers

Let $n$ be a strict positive integer and $x$ is a complex number.
Define $f_n(x)$ as one of the solutions to

$$ f_n (x)^{2n} + f_n ' (x)^{2n} = 1$$

Where the derivative is with respect to $x$.

Why is every entire solution $f_n(x) $ periodic on the complex plane ?

For instance the solutions for $f_1(x)$ are ${-1, 1, -\sin(x),\sin(x),-\cos(x),\cos(x)}$.
All of them are periodic with period $2 \pi$.

I assume implicit differentiation helps.

Comment: Is this a guess? or You are sure about it? :)

Comment: Well what does it mean to be sure without a proof ;) ? @H.R.    Anyway I think euler proved n=2,3 and 4.

Comment: I just thought that it is a justified theorem that you are seeking for some proof! :)

Comment: What do you mean by **entire** solution? If you mean **all**, we have an counter example below! :) where did that **complex** came from! :D

Comment: Entire function means a function that is analytic everywhere ( at every finite complex number ). I pulled the complex out of my hat. :)

Comment: Shall we forget about complex plane and stay on the real line! :) There can be analytic functions on real line too! :) I hate complex plane as my complex analysis is not good! :D

Comment: @H.R. Blame Robert for that ! He forced it with a counterexample ;)

Comment: Maybe some solutions with some good properties (that I don't know what) are periodic! we may seek for the properties that the Robert's counter example does not have and focus on that! :)

Comment: As an example it is not infinitely differentiable on the real line or analytic in the complex plane as you like! :)

Comment: I think what is probably true is that there exists a periodic solution to the equation.

Comment: I considered fourrier series , but they do not care about analytic which is problematic ; like you can have $x^2$ being periodic with those darn fourier series ...

Comment: Or what about the condition that $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x)$ does not exist? That might do it... actually it won't, come to think of it. You can stitch together humps that behave nonperiodically.

Answer (score 0):

Actually they are not all periodic.  For example, one solution (for $n=1$) is
$$ f_1(x) = \cases{-1 & $x \le -\pi/2$ \cr
\sin(x) & $-\pi/2 \le x < \pi/2$\cr
1 & $x \ge \pi/2$\cr} $$

EDIT: For $n > 1$, the non-constant solutions will not be entire, or even real-analytic:  they won't be analytic at $x_0$ where $f(x_0) = 1$.  If $f(x_0) = 1$ and the first nonzero term after the constant term in the Taylor series of $f$ at $x_0$ is $a (x-x_0)^m$, we would have
$f(x)^{2n}  = 1 + 2 n a (x-x_0)^m + \ldots$ while $f'(x)^{2n} = (am)^{2n} (x-x_0)^{2n(m-1)} + \ldots$, and $2n(m-1) > m$ if $m \ge 2$, so we can't get this series to work.

For example, for $n=2$ a non-constant solution with $f(0) = 1$ has the 
Puiseux series
$$ 1 - \frac{1}{4} (3x)^{4/3} + \frac{3}{224} (3x)^{8/3}- \frac{53}{68992} (3x)^4 + \frac{1081}{115906560} (3x)^{16/3} + 
\ldots$$
and thus it's not analytic: $x=0$ is a branch point.

Comment: This misses the spirit of the question.

Comment: I added the word entire. In a hope to not miss the spirit of the questions ... However im not sure all solutions are entire ... And even if they are , i clearly lack the words to get the spirit of the idea ... Analytic comes to Mind but Robert's answer is also analytic almost everywhere. Analytic continuation also comes to mind. I think x being complex and being periodic in the complex plane does the trick.

Comment: I think I edited accordingly. Hope the OP is now improved.

Comment: That should be n = 1 in the answer. My fault , i originally wrote $f_2$ in the OP myself. But following the def its n = 1.

Comment: On behalf of Robert , i thank you for the edit @H.R. :)

Comment: @mick: On behalf of myself! you are welcome! :D

Comment: @nayrb I wanted to comment at the second answer, but it got removed. I did not accept it / or not understand it. I believe it was yours. Found a mistake I assume ?

Comment: Yes mick, I made a couple mistakes. I had a few good ideas but made an algebra mistake when using an inequality that makes it not work.

Comment: " $f(x)^{2n}  = 1 + 2 n a (x-x_0)^m + \ldots$ while $f'(x)^{2n} = (am)^{2n} (x-x_0)^{2n(m-1)} + \ldots$, and $2n(m-1) > m$ if $m \ge 2$, so we can't get this series to work. " <quote> That is nonsense. Sorry. The exponents dont match and even the sine is a counterexample. -1 ( for now , might undo ).

Comment: The sine is for $n=1$, this is $n > 1$.

Comment: If $f(x) = 1 + a (x-x_0)^m + \ldots$, then $f(x)^{2n} = 1 + 2 n a (x - x_0)^m + \ldots$.  $f'(x) = a m (x - x_0)^{m-1} + \ldots$ so $f'(x)^{2n} = (am)^{2n} (x-x_0)^{2n(m-1)} + \ldots$.

Comment: Hmm ok Maybe ... Will think about it.

Comment: But a branch point does not exclude periodic right ?

Comment: Maybe $f(x^3)$ is periodic ? I wonder about a closed form for the coëfficiënts of the puiseux series.

Comment: If a solution $f$ (defined on the reals) is not constant on any interval of positive length, then it must be periodic.